# Load csv file, using python

Tags: python, json, csv, pickle

```
Beijing, China, [123,456,789,11]
Tokyo, Japan, [153,456,788,12]
Seoul, Korea, [144,559,363,211]
```

Using python, I would like to load this format of csv file.
I know there are lots to achieve this. Show me some relevant smart way.
I especially wish to know the way using pickle module.

The points are...

1. input file should be csv file, not json file.
2. the 3rd item is a sequence, each number separated with ",". and should have "[" for beginning, and "]" for end.
3. output is not defined. I am thinking of dictionary with "Country", "City", and "Value" keys.

Comment: This is not a good question. You need to show how you have tried to solve this problem yourself before you ask other people to help you.

Comment: I would recommend using pandas as a start [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and if that does not work you can update your question

Comment: What makes you think that *pickle* might be useful for this?

Comment: @JeppeHolt Can *pandas* handle that format? Perhaps you could give an example as an answer to this question

Comment: Python also has a standard [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: @Pingu I heard pickle is useful to load binary to some python typical type object. In this case I expected that this file should convert to something like,
[["Beijing", "China", [123,456,789,11]],
["Tokyo", "Japan", [153,456,788,12]],
["Seoul", "Korea", [144,559,363,211]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only complication here is the evaluation of the third column. You could use *literal_eval* from the *ast* module as follows:

```
from ast import literal_eval

FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.csv'

result = []

with open(FILENAME) as csv:
    for line in csv:
        city, country, values = map(lambda t: t.rstrip(','), line.split())
        result.append({'city': city, 'country': country, 'values': literal_eval(values)})

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'city': 'Beijing', 'country': 'China', 'values': [123, 456, 789, 11]}, {'city': 'Tokyo', 'country': 'Japan', 'values': [153, 456, 788, 12]}, {'city': 'Seoul', 'country': 'Korea', 'values': [144, 559, 363, 211]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I didn't know ast module.